# Inheriting interface in Vala - incompatible with base method

Tags: c, gtk, vala, gobject

I'm trying to implement a `Gtk.StyleProvider` in Vala. The "base class" (in C) looks like:

```
GtkIconFactory *        gtk_style_provider_get_icon_factory ()
GtkStyleProperties *    gtk_style_provider_get_style ()
gboolean                gtk_style_provider_get_style_property ()
```

and in VAPI:

```
[CCode (cheader_filename = "gtk/gtk.h")]
public interface StyleProvider {
    public abstract unowned Gtk.IconFactory get_icon_factory (Gtk.WidgetPath path);
    public abstract unowned Gtk.StyleProperties get_style (Gtk.WidgetPath path);
    public abstract bool get_style_property (Gtk.WidgetPath path, Gtk.StateFlags state, GLib.ParamSpec pspec, GLib.Value value);
}
```

Where the first two methods should only return `NULL` according to the documentation for `GtkStyleProvider`.

Thus, I wrote some Vala like this:

```
public class DerivedStyleProvider : Gtk.StyleProvider
{
    public Gtk.IconFactory? get_icon_factory (Gtk.WidgetPath path)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public Gtk.StyleProperties? get_style (Gtk.WidgetPath path)
    {
        return null;
    }

    bool get_style_property (Gtk.WidgetPath path,
                    Gtk.StateFlags state,
                    GLib.ParamSpec pspec,
                    out GLib.Value value)
    {
        return false; //TODO
    }
}
```

I have a problem with the first two methods. If I have them as written here (with a `?`), then I get the following error:

```
error: overriding method `DerivedStyleProvider.get_icon_factory' is incompatible 
with base method `Gtk.StyleProvider.get_icon_factory': Base method expected 
return type `Gtk.IconFactory', but `Gtk.IconFactory?' was provided.
    public Gtk.IconFactory? get_icon_factory (Gtk.WidgetPath path)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `gtk_style_provider_get_style()` method is the same.

If I remove the `?`, I get the following two errors per method:

```
error: overriding method `DerivedsStyleProvider.get_icon_factory' 
is incompatible with base method `Gtk.StyleProvider.get_icon_factory': Base 
method expected return type `Gtk.IconFactory', but `Gtk.IconFactory' was provided.
        public Gtk.IconFactory get_icon_factory (Gtk.WidgetPath path)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
src/Preferences.vala:138.3-138.14: warning: `null' incompatible with 
return type `Gtk.IconFactory`
                return null;
                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The first error especially is a bit strange to me, as the upshot is "error: expected TYPE, got TYPE"!

Adding `unowned` to the first two methods still results in similar errors.

How should I implement a `Gtk.StyleProvider` interface in Vala?

Comment: You have to specify the methods as `public override Gtk...` (note the override keyword). Also the method signature must match exactly, so you have to use `unowned` where the parent method uses `unowned` and you can't just introduce nullable (`?`) where the parent method doesn't use nullable ...

Comment: Even adding `override` and removing nullable results in `error: PreferencesStyleProvider.get_icon_factory: no suitable method found to override`. And if I can't return `null`, how to meet the documented requirements?

Comment: You can return null, since Gtk.IconFactory is a class type, are you by any chance using the experimental non-null mode? The VAPI file needs fixing anyway, it should be nullable in the vapi file.

Comment: Also I just now realize that Gtk.StyleProvider is not an abstract class, but an interface. Sorry about that, to implement interfaces `override` is not necessary AFAIK.

Comment: I don't see `--enable-experimental-non-null` in the `valac` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles without errors or warnings on my system (Vala 0.32.1):

```
public class DerivedStyleProvider : GLib.Object, Gtk.StyleProvider
{
    public unowned Gtk.IconFactory get_icon_factory (Gtk.WidgetPath path)
    {
        // Evil cast to work around buggy declaration in VAPI file
        return (Gtk.IconFactory) null;
    }

    public Gtk.StyleProperties get_style (Gtk.WidgetPath path)
    {
        // Evil cast to work around buggy declaration in VAPI file
        return (Gtk.StyleProperties) null;
    }

    bool get_style_property (Gtk.WidgetPath path,
                    Gtk.StateFlags state,
                    GLib.ParamSpec pspec,
                    out GLib.Value value)
    {
        // I just assigned something here to make the compiler happy, you should make sure to use a correct value
        value = Value (typeof (string));
        return false; //TODO
    }
}
```

I made these changes:

- Derive from `GLib.Object` in addition to the interface.
- Use `unowned` on the first method.
- Remove the nullable from the return types.
- Cast null into the actual class types. (Which is not pretty, but the problem is with the vapi file.)
- Assign a dummy value to the out parameter to make compiling warning free ;)

Comment: Looks like I picked a wrong class to use for my first Vala interface experience!

Comment: Thank you, it works for me now as well! This explains several Vala concepts clearly!

Comment: You're welcome, that's what SO is for, we always look forward to help users with well-described problems/questions :).